# DataTables: Filter on custom data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to filter a DataTable by selecting a filter from a select-input.

```html
<select class="form-control filter-table" data-column="language">
  <option selected>Alle Sprachen</option>
  <option value="GER">Deutsch</option>
  <option value="ENG">Englisch</option>
</select>
```

That's how my table is designed:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Hello</td>  <td data-language="ENG">Englisch</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hello</td>  <td data-language="GER">German</td>
</tr>
```

Here's my event handler:

```javascript
$('.filter-table').change(function (e) {
    var column = $(this).data('column');
    var filter = $(this).val();
});
```

I already searched quite a while but did not find an answer

Comment: Just curious, are you searching for the answer related exactly to jQuery plug-in DataTables or you're searching for generic jQuery solution for arbitrary table? If former is the case, what exactly do you mean by 'filter on custom data attribute', should matching row have same text as selected option or same (arbitrary) attribute value?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using DataTables Jquery Plugin.

```
<select id="dropdown1" class="form-control filter-table" data-column="language">
<option selected>Alle Sprachen</option>
<option value="GER">Deutsch</option>
<option value="ENG">Englisch</option>
</select>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Greeting</th>
            <th>Language</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tr>
<td>Hello</td>  <td data-language="ENG">Englisch</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Hello</td>  <td data-language="GER">German</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table =  $('#example').DataTable();

 $('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {
     if(this.value=="Alle Sprachen")
      {
      table.columns(1).search('').draw();
      }
      else
      {
      table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
      }                   
   } );

});
```

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/an5kbx0z/

Comment: Updated fiddle with the implementation of 'Select All' functionality for the data table.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to look for generic jQuery solution, you might check out this one:

```js
 //populate options
 $('#lang').append([...$('#mytable tr td:nth-of-type(2)')].sort().reduce((options, option) => options+=`<option value="${$(option).text()}">${$(option).text()}</option>`,'<option value="All" selected>All</option>'));
 
  //grab table data
 const tableDataObj = {};
 tableDataObj.data = [...$('#mytable tbody tr')].map(row => {
  const rowObj = {};
  [...$(row).children('td')].forEach((cell, index) => rowObj[$(`#mytable thead th:eq(${index})`).text()] = $(cell).text());
  return rowObj;
 });
 tableDataObj.header = [];
 tableDataObj.data.map(row => Object.keys(row)).flat().forEach(entry => {
  if(tableDataObj.header.indexOf(entry) == -1) tableDataObj.header.push(entry);
 });
 
  //draw table upon selection
 $('#lang').on('change', function() {
  const filteredData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableDataObj));
  filteredData.data = filteredData.data.filter(entry => entry.Language == $(this).val() || $(this).val() == 'All');
  $('#mytable').html('<table></table>');
  $('#mytable').append('<thead><tr>'+filteredData.header.reduce((thead, th) => thead+=`<th>${th}</th>`,''));
  $('#mytable').append(`<tbody>${Object.values(filteredData.data).reduce((rows, row) => rows+='<tr>'+Object.values(row).reduce((tds, td) => tds += '<td>'+td+'</td>','')+'</tr>','')}</tbody>`);
 });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body>
   <select id="lang"></select>
   <table id="mytable">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Greeting</th><th>Language</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Hello</td><td>English</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Hallo</td><td>Deutsch</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Selam</td><td>Turkce</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Salut</td><td>Francais</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Ciao</td><td>Italiano</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </body>
 </html>
```

It is not that elegant and scalable, however, delivers general idea.

If you were requesting for DataTables solution, I may recommend [this](https://github.com/ygorbunkov/datatables-multiple-criteria-filter) plug-in. With it you don't need to use extra drop-downs - it is neat and simple, even though in its early release, fulfills your requirement perfectly. With that approach, you may get multiple select filters in addition to basic DataTables sorting, pagination/scrolling. Here is the [**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/NJWmwE?editors=1010).